# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer uso de android.support.annotation?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer uso de **BluetoothAdapter.java** pero no funciona debido a que no puede resolver símbolos como `IntDef`, `RequiresPermission`, etc...

Este es el código donde lo uso.

```
btnNewPairing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


                if(arrayDevices != null)
                    arrayDevices.clear();

            // Comprobamos si existe un descubrimiento en curso. En caso afirmativo, se cancela.
               if(bAdapter.isDiscovering())
                 bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                // Iniciamos la busqueda de dispositivos y mostramos el mensaje de que el proceso ha comenzado
                if(bAdapter.startDiscovery())
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Iniciando búsqueda de dispositivos bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error al iniciar búsqueda de dispositivos bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Y las dependencias son las siguientes:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    /* androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
                    })*/
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
}
```

¿ALGUIEN PUEDE AYUDARME?
Gracias

Comment: El problema es que no reconoce esta dependencia? compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes verificar en al pagina oficial de Android tiene un apartado que hablan del `https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Permissions` y `https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html`. Ya que la información y fragmentos de código que das, no se logra ver cual es el problema.

Saludos

Comment: Las respuestas con enlaces no son del todo válidas, Te recomiendo [edit] tu respuesta y mejorarla según se puede leer aquí: **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Saludos.